# Flowchart layout connecting single data to multiple process in the flow

Tags: workflow, data-visualisation

I have got a program in which same database has to be accessed multiple time and single data has to be used at multiple points. Proccess 1 uses raw data 1 and db 1. Process 2 uses results from process 1 and raw data 1 and db 1 again.

I am concerned if having a solid line would represent there to be a flow from that data to two processes when it is not the case. It is more like revisiting the same data twice in during the process.
Also, same database has to be accessed twice.
How can I represent such a scenario with flowchart?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the image you have indicates what you've described well enough.

I mean you could tweak things I suppose, but it's just a matter of preference as to how the paths appear.

I might do something like....

[image] or [image]

This assumes the end result is a single output. If there are multiple outputs from `Process 2`, based upon the different inputs, then I might indicate multiple outputs.

Comment: Process 2 uses result from process 1 and the data 1 and db 1 again

Comment: @menten So P2 uses raw Data 1, P1 results, *and* the DB? The question doesn't indicate P2 is using raw Data 1, in fact, just the opposite.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. But yes, it uses raw data again

Comment: Thank you. It seems to make things more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a line coming in from top and bottom, you could merge those lines and make a small line coming off of that, pointing toward the process...
[image]